# How to make an invisible combobox list visible?

Tags: c#, xaml

Hello my drop down list for my `RadRibbonComboBox` is populated, But the font is in white and making it nearly invisible to read. May I ask how do I change the Colour Font of the items in the comboboxlist.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCUl3.jpg)

Xaml Code:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonComboBox 
    FontFamily="arial" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="ExtraBold" 
    CanAutocompleteSelectItems="False" CanKeyboardNavigationSelectItems="True" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    telerik:ScreenTip.Description="Change the font family." IsReadOnly="True" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding RegisteredFonts, Source={StaticResource FontFamiliesProvider}}"
    MaxDropDownHeight="400" OpenDropDownOnFocus="True" telerik:RadRichTextBoxRibbonUI.RichTextCommand="{Binding ChangeFontFamilyCommand}" 
    telerik:ScreenTip.Title="Font" Width="132">
</telerik:RadRibbonComboBox>
```

Comment: here's a link to the docs on styling the combo box http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radribbonview-styling-ribboncombobox.html

Comment: I'm trying to directly apply it on the XAML

Answer (score 0):

As stated on this page you are going to want to set the Foreground color of your RadRibbonComboBox. This should change the font color that is drawn to the screen. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Just add the following ID to your code.

```
Foreground="{Color}"
```

For color you can choose to either put the colors name, or the hexcode value for the color. Here's an image of all available preset colors.

[image: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC210551.png]

Comment: Not quite yet, It makes selected font appear but the list is still is still white.

Comment: I'm thinking there's something related to the binding. But i was hoping it could possibly inherit the type From the Parent

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark, but try changing the Background="{color}" ID also.

Comment: Same situation, It makes that top box colour change. Not the drop down list.